# How to change page title of password reset form?

Tags: django

I am using the default password reset form, that comes with django..I have changed the title of Admin Site by adding the following line of code in urls.py

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site Name'
```

But, the password rest form still says "Django Administration" in place of the site title, as show in the image attached. How do I change it?
[Password Reset Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvkOY.png)

Comment: A solution is now suggested in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature).

Answer (score 6):

Although [reset_password_form.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html) is extended from `admin/base_site.html`. But it seems the `site_header` text is not sent from view to template(maybe because its not part of the actual admin site or the templates are there for example purpose). So you can create a new View subclassing from `django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView` and pass this information via `context`. Try like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.contrib import admin


class CustomResetPasswordView(PasswordResetView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kw):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kw)
        context['site_header'] = getattr(admin.sites, 'site_header')  # get site header text. For django 2.X it should be getattr(admin.sites.AdminSite, 'site_header')
        return context
```

and use it in your urls:

```
path('reset_passowrd/', CustomResetPasswordView.as_view()),
```

**OR**

Write a context processor which sends `site_header`, like this:

```
# your_app/context_processors.py
def admin_header_processor(request):
    site_header = getattr(admin.sites, 'site_header')  # get site header text. For django 2.X it should be 
    return {"site_header": site_header}
```

And add this to `context_processors` inside `TEMPLATES`:

```
'context_processors': [
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'your_app.context_processors.admin_header_processor',
],
```

Comment: `site_header` is an attribute of [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes)

Comment: Context processor worked like a charm for me. Thank you!

Comment: For the context processor the import is `from django.contrib import admin` and **the object containing the attributes is `admin.site`, not `admin.sites`**

Comment: The docs for Django 5.0 suggest [yet another alternative](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature), viz. to add the `site_header` to `extra_context` via the URLconf. Also see [issue 34677](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34677#comment:2).