# Django /accounts reset page personalization

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

In my django project i have my default page for reset password option:

[image]

i need to:

- Modify 'Django Administration' header with my own
- Remove the 'Home > Password reset' menu

I try with this code in admin.py for the first point:

```
admin.site.site_title = 'Aida Admin'
admin.site.site_header = 'Aida admin console'
admin.site.index_title = 'SETTINGS ADMIN ADMINISTRATION'
```

but don't seems to work

Someone have an idea?
So many thanks in advance

Comment: this you have to add in main urls.py file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change page title of password reset form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572151/how-to-change-page-title-of-password-reset-form)

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py you can override the 3 most important variables:

```
admin.site.site_title = 'Aida Admin'
admin.site.site_header = 'Aida admin console'
admin.site.index_title = 'SETTINGS ADMIN ADMINISTRATION'
```